# MySQL server has gone away on simple select query

Tags: mysql

since any weeks I have a problem with a simple SQL Query where from time to time the mySQL Server has gone away. But in the last time I have this crashes every day 1,2 times day.

The query is very simple:

SELECT ... from table where field = 'some string' LIMIT 1

The table has 15 rows and the "field" where the query selects is an index. The explain is very good and shows that the index is used.

The table is innodb. At the beginning I have used MyISAM but the problem is the same. After the crashes began I have transform it into InnoDB but this does not helpes.

Where can be the problem here?

Server version: 5.0.51a-24+lenny3 (Debian)
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.51a, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

Thank you very much!

Cheers
Nik

Comment: Does it crash the server every time you run the query, or just occasionally?

Comment: I vote to move this to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) as this seems more of a DB admin question and you may get some good answers there.

Comment: Yep. I would have expected some sort of hardware issue perhaps. When it crashes do you get any message in any log files?

Answer (score 2):

If your data is corrupted then it can cause the exact symptoms you're describing.

Try running a `CHECK TABLE table` to confirm and a `REPAIR TABLE table` to resolve.